# Why does Cake Bake don't pluralize User at entity?

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I have a model called `users` and another called `permissions`. I just generated both with `cake bake model all` and I got this:

User Entity:

```
protected $_accessible = [
    'email' => true,
    'password' => true,
    'permissions' => true, // Plural
];
```

Permission Entity:

```
protected $_accessible = [
    'user_id' => true,
    'controller' => true,
    'user' => true, // Singular
];
```

Is this a `Bake` error or theres some kind of logic behind it?

Comment: And what is your question exactly?

Comment: Let me guess, it's `Users hasMany Permissions` and `Permissions belongsTo Users`?

Comment: Hey @anantkumarsingh if you read you can notice two questions, first: 'Why bake dont pluralize users' and second: 'this is a Bake error or theres some kind of logic behind it?'

Comment: It's the convention of cake php not any error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is explained in the CakePHP 3 docs, under [Inflection Rules Updated](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/orm-migration.html#inflection-rules-updated)

> BelongsTo and HasOne associations will use the singular form in entity
>   properties, while HasMany and BelongsToMany (HABTM) will use plural
>   forms.

In other words, `user` is singular because it's related by a belongsTo / hasOne association. `permissions` is plural because it's related by a hasMany or HABTM association.

This can understandably catch folks off-guard if they're migrating from CakePHP 2, but it's actually pretty intuitive. Each permission has one *user* it's been granted to, but each user might have multiple *permissions* granted.